# How to send JSONArray string to php server using multipart entity in android

Tags: php, android, multipartentity

I am unable to send JSONArray string to php server using multipart entity in android. I have tried following but it's not working:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,BOUNDARY,Charset.defaultCharset());
entity.addPart("invite_friend", new StringBody(friendsArray));
```

In PHP server side it should come like:

```
'invite_friend' => array
    (
        0 => '800'
        1 => '794'
    )
```

What could be done, please provide suggestions.

Comment: its not a `JSONArray`

Comment: refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050533/how-to-send-file-in-json-on-android/18050865#18050865

Comment: that "friendsArray" contains like ["800","794"] in string value pair: "invite_friend":["800","794"]. How to send this "["800","794"]" data using Multipart.

Comment: its a `StringArray`...not `JSONArray`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
// Prepare Category Array
for (String mFrndsID : friendsArray) {
    reqEntity.addPart("invite_friend[]", new StringBody(mFrndsID));
}
```

Just add [] with you array tag and paas values in a loop in it.
Here invite_friend is the array tag. You can pass your values in this tag by using loop. it will post as an array on server.

Refer This Answer for more detail

[How to send the string array of values in one key word using post method to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293388/how-to-send-the-string-array-of-values-in-one-key-word-using-post-method-to-the/16293445#16293445)

this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for sending multiple value pairs to server side scripts.

```
String strUrl = "http://****/****.php";
url = new URL(strUrl);

HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
        .openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(
        connection.getOutputStream());

outputStreamWriter.write("user_names_giver=" +user_names_giver + "&tcredit="+tcredit+"&user_name_receiver="+user_name_receiver);                
outputStreamWriter.flush();
outputStreamWriter.close();

InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
InputStreamReader(iStream));

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

String line = "";

while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    sb.append(line);
}

reader.close();
iStream.close();
```