# How to make JSONarray of object using MultipartEntity?

Tags: android, apache, android-asynctask, http-post, multipart

I have to post such json using MultipartEntity.

```
{
arrayName":[
  {
    // object one
  },
  {
    // object two
  }]
}
```

I don't get an idea how to make such structure once posting multipartEntity object, what i have tried so far is.

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("key","value");
.....
.....
..... all keys 
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Is there any way so i can make MultipartEntity array or what?

NOTE: for separate posting one json object it work very fine. I just want to learn how to create JSONarry format, once posting with MultipartEntity.

Comment: you can also post Array using `new StringBody(Array)`

Comment: But how do i post MultipartEntity as an array. please explain. understand my case

Comment: please see following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293388/how-to-send-the-string-array-of-values-in-one-key-word-using-post-method-to-the   let me know it is help full for u

Comment: I have seen it already. My case is different. this is posting an array within jsonobject. i have to post an array of jsonobjects.

Comment: Then do not use MultipartEntity. Just post the json text.

Comment: I have to upload image as well within that object. then how can i upload FileBody?

Comment: base64 encoded in a json parameter.

Comment: server doesn't receive this way.

Comment: No? You should then tell how the server wants to receive all.

Comment: This isn't problem, focus what i have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your json array to string.

Use Gson Library for that. [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Now you just have to use like this.
Whatever you model is so

```
ArrayList<CustomClass> objects = new ArrayList<>();
objects.add(object);
objects.add(object);
```

and then just use gson.

```
String stringToPost = new Gson().toJson(objects);
```

then add multipart this string as

```
Stringbody
```

Server side will **deserialize String to Json Array.**

Also you can add file as **filebody** in **multipart**.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to upload image and JSONArray using MultipartEntity-- lib:org.apache.http.entity.mime

```
List students = getStudentList();

MultipartEntity studentList = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

for(int i=0; i<students.size();i++){

    try {
        studentList.addPart("studentList[][name]", new StringBody(String.valueOf(students.get(i).getName())));
        studentList.addPart("studentList[][addmission_no]", new StringBody(String.valueOf(students.get(i).getAddmissionNo)));
        studentList.addPart("studentList[][gender]", new StringBody(String.valueOf(students.get(i).getGender)));

        File photoImg = new File(students.get(i).getImagePath());
        studentList.addPart("studentList[][photo]",new FileBody(photoImg,"image/jpeg"));


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
    }
}

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

post.addHeader("X-Auth-Token", mUserToken);
post.setEntity(studentList);

org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = null;
try {
    response =  client.execute(post);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
JSONObject myObject;
try {
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
   // do your work

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```